# How to set up a function to highlight the existence of a set of two specific values within a table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm setting up a google sheet (they won't let me use excel, unfortunately :/) to track shifts at stations for a pool that I manage. There are pairs of people that I want to avoid scheduling to work together. I'd like my sheet to highlight the names of pairs of people in a table if I have scheduled those two people to work at the same time.

I've tried using a `COUNTIF` function and putting pairs of people that I don't want to work together in named ranges (the sheet is named Duties!), then pulling from the named range, e.g. `Duties!E12:F12`. My table has values `E2:M10` so the function looked something like

```
=COUNTIF(E2:M10,E2)=Duties!E12:F12
```

However, that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

- let's say you have a table **A1:D12** and **`a`** and **`b`** can't be next to each other:
- custom formula: `=COUNTIFS(A1, "a" ,B1, "b")` applied to range **A1:D12**
- custom formula: `=COUNTIFS(A1, "a" ,B1, "b")` applied to range **B1:E12**

  [image: 0]
- if **`a`** and **`b`** are on **Sheet2** in **A1** and **B1** you use `INDIRECT` like:
- `=COUNTIFS(A1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1") ,B1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!B1"))`